Show that expectation of a random vector which is in a convex set with probability one belongs in said convex set
The book Convex Optimization (BV) on P25 claims that if $x$ is a random vector with $x \in C$ with probability one, where $C \subseteq \textbf{R}^{n}$ is a convex set, then $\textbf{E}[x] \in C$
It does not elaborate further on why this holds when $\textbf{E}[x]$ is a sum of infinite number of terms or an integral (as stated in the first and second case in the book respectively). I intuitively know these statements could hold, but I would like to have a formal proof. Searching through the asked question I only found more generalized question involving complex number, and the answer involves concepts in analysis which I am not (yet) familar with.
I was wondering if there is a simpler proof or even an informal but convincing argument that is more than just typical intuitive interpretation regarding this statement?

If $n=1$, and $C=[a,b]$, then $a\leq x\leq b$ with probability $1$. Then, $\mathbb a\leq E[x]\leq b$. I let you adapt for $n$ and $C$ unspecified.

Let us consider a simple case with two-dim random vector $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and assume $P(X\in D)=1$ for a closed convex set $D$.
Assume by contradiction that $E[X]\notin D$. Then by separating hyperplane theorem, there exists a line $l$ separate the set $D$ and the point $E[X]$. Performing some rotation $\rho$ you can make this line horizontal. Wolg, say $\rho(D)$ is below the horizontal line and $\rho(E[X])$ is above.
Let $Y=\rho(X)$, then $\rho(E[X])=E[Y]$ is above the horizontal line while $Y$ is completely contained in set $\rho(D)$ below the horizontal line. This is impossible.
This argument should generalize to $n$-dim and non-closed convex set. But I haven't verified it.

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer by @goldboy. But the answer is incomplete. For example, consider $(X_1,X_2)$ lives in the unit ball. His argument only shows that $(E[X_1],E[X_2])$ is in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Yes, you're right. I deleted my post.
